# Question about removal of duplicates in NLP, when specifically working on twitter data

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

Should we remove the duplicates before pre-processing or after pre-processing in NLP specifically when working on the twitter data? Actually main concern for me is that duplicates after pre-processing may have come from different tweets and so removing duplicates after pre-processing would be incorrect right? These are my thoughts, can confirm and give a clear insight about this?

Comment: What kind of duplicates are you talking about? if you have a dataset with duplicate rows, simply drop them as first thing, after loading data.

Comment: @Oscar I am talking about the duplicate tweets when working with Twitter data. So, are you saying that after pre-processing there is no need to remove the duplicates?

Comment: It depends which task you're doing, please give more detail.

Comment: @SaiSreenivas if you have data with no duplicates (because you removed them) before pre-processing, why should you remove duplicates after such operation?

Comment: @Oscar Thanks for the reply. Actually I had a doubt whether to remove the duplicates after pre-processing because they may be treated as redundancy (similar to the duplicates before pre-processing) and I had also one more argument that duplicates after pre-processing are from different tweets so that it would be incorrect to remove duplicates because we are losing information from that (duplicates) tweets. So you say the second argument is valid and not to remove the duplicates after pre-processing right?

Comment: I think you are saying too few to get an answer, you should give more details and explain your problem from start-to-finish in order to get an answer.